# Java FX 8, trouble setting the value of text field

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to populate the value of a text field in Java FX.

I have the Main Class,the controller and the fxml.I have bind the fxml file with controller and the appropriate field in it. When i try to set its value, it fails.

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private FlowPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {


            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("test.fxml"));            
            rootLayout = (FlowPane) loader.load();                      
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();



        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

testController.java

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class testController {

    @FXML
    private TextField t1;

    public testController() {

        System.out.println("hi");
        t1 = new TextField("j");
        t1.setText("hi");

    }



}
```

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>

<FlowPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.testController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="t1" />
   </children>
</FlowPane>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing it in the wrong place! If you need to play around with your controls just before your fxml is loaded, you need to do it in the [`initialize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize). For this your controller should implement the [`Initializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)

So your controller becomes :

```
public class testController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TextField t1;

    public void initialize() {

        System.out.println("hi");

        //You should not re-initialize your textfield
        //t1 = new TextField("j");

        t1.setText("hi");

    }
}
```