# JavaFX Label is not displaying text

Tags: javafx-2

I have created a Label and assigned it a string which contains a constant variable name in it. I then gave the FXML label the fx:idea of the label in the controller which was annotated with @FXML:
FXML File:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="387.0" prefWidth="444.0" 
 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" 
 xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
 fx:controller="application.HomeController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="welcomeMsg" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="16.0" 
       prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="428.0" textAlignment="CENTER" 
       textOverrun="CLIP" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HomeController {
public String appName = "Probability Distribution Calculator";
@FXML
private Label welcomeMsg = new Label("Welcome to the "+appName);
}
```

The label displays the styles I have given it, however, the text is not displaying. If I assign a static text attribute to the FXML element it works, but when I try to assign the name with the controller it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java FX 8, trouble setting the value of text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189984/java-fx-8-trouble-setting-the-value-of-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

i think your controller should be extends from `Initializable`

and you should not do `welcomeMsg = new Label("Welcome to the "+appName)` because `welcomeMsg` will be assigned to label in fxml after the loading of view complete and also do not make the variable `private`

```
public class HomeController extends Initializable {
     public String appName = "Probability Distribution Calculator";
     @FXML Label welcomeMsg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ali is right. You should use the setText method of the Label class to set your welcome message. Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/label.htm