# How to set updated value in textfield

Tags: javafx, textfield

I have set a value in text field. If I change the value in textfield how to set updated value in text field in javafx?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189984/java-fx-8-trouble-setting-the-value-of-text-field

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
TextField notification = new TextField ();
notification.setText("Label");
```

By calling setText method of textfield object.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It sets the value to Label. I want if I run the program and write Label1 in text field, then value be set to Label1.

Comment: If you are type directly in textfield then is't it directly set to textfield. Why you need to set it externally.